# How to shorten (replace) query of 2 CTE into 1 JOIN LATERAL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
ID  platform_order_number
-------------------------
1          B2CQWE
2          B2CWER
3          B2BZXC
4          XCV
```

I want to extract a few rows (2 for this case) for every different platform like this

```
ID  platform_order_number    platform
--------------------------------------
#          B2CQWE               B2C
#          B2CWER               B2C
#          B2BZXC               B2B
#          B2BXCV               B2B
#          ABC                  C2C
#          EDF                  C2C
```

My success code:

```
with cte as 
(
    select id, platform_order_number,
    case when platform_order_number LIKE 'B2C%' then 'B2C'
         when platform_order_number LIKE 'B2B%' then 'C2C'
         else 'C2C'
    end as platform
    from table
),
cte1 as 
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by platform order by platform) 
    as count_row_by_platform from cte 
)
select * 
from cte1
where count_row_by_platform < 2
```

It's a bit complicated, so I try to make it simple as below (but it's not working)

```
select id, platform_order_number, sub_table.row_count
from apollo.packages 
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (ROW_NUMBER() over 
                      (partition by platform_order_number order by 
                       platform_order_number) as row_count
                       from apollo.packages ) as sub_table
where sub_table.row_count <= 2
```

Since, I need to add many different conditions on different columns so I want to keep my query simple to add and change condition easily.

> PostgreSQL 11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
> compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit

Comment: Can you break down your problem you got into a tiny, yet complete, example, that shows the source data, and the expected output

Comment: Note that `count_row_by_platform < 2` will only extract **one** row per platform, not 2. Did you mean to write `<= 2`? If you want only one row per platform it can't be done using `distinct  on ()` which makes things a bit shorter, but for <= 2 you will need to use a two stage approach. I don't think the lateral join makes things easier in any way though. The two CTEs are a good solution in my opinion. If I did any change, I might probably change that to two derived tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.id, t.platform_order_number, v.platform,
             row_number() over (partition by v.platform order by t.platform_order_number) as seqnum
       from table t cross apply lateral
            (values (case when platform_order_number LIKE 'B2C%' then 'B2C'
                          when platform_order_number LIKE 'B2B%' then 'C2C'
                          else 'C2C'
                     end)
            ) v(platform)
      ) t;
```

In general, window functions may not behave as expected in a lateral join.  They only work on the rows processed in the lateral join (often just one row) rather than spanning the original table.